# functional correctness of wiki mersenne twister pseudocode

Tags: python, random, mersenne-twister

can anyone tell me if the mersenne twister pseudocode on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Pseudocode) page is the same as the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469031/open-source-implementation-of-mersenne-twister-in-python)? if they are not the same, which one is correct?

Comment: Have you tried running them both and comparing their outputs?

Comment: yeah. they come out differently, even when i get them both to output as decimal/integers

Comment: How did you run the pseudocode on the wikipedia page?

Comment: i changed it to python and ran it. i used 4357 as the seed for both

Comment: And did you correctly use mod 2 ** 32 arithmetic when you translated it into python?

Comment: i think so. i modded where that the wiki pseudocode said 'last 32/31 bits of...'