# Mersenne Twister in python

Tags: python, random, hex, code-translation

In an attempt to better understand the Mersenne Twister (MT) I decided to convert it into python. [Here](https://repl.it/Gh3G) you can run the code and see the commented C source code at the bottom.

The code runs but I'm not getting the expected output. Based on the C output [here](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/emt19937ar.html) The first numbers I should be getting are `1067595299  955945823  477289528 4107218783 4228976476` but I'm getting `2594155707 3648022958 667752806 3967333545 3535325493`.

---

Side note:

I found another implementation on SO saying they got the same output as C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470458/3462319) but when I run it in [python2](https://repl.it/Gip0) or [python3](https://repl.it/GipZ) (xrange->range and no L in hexadecimal) the output also doesn't match Cs expected, it gives `0.817330 0.999061 0.510354 0.131533 0.035416` instead of the expected `0.76275443 0.99000644 0.98670464 0.10143112 0.27933125`. ... If you're wondering changing my code to give a result in [0,1) interval gives `0.6039989429991692 0.8493715333752334 0.15547331562265754 0.9237168228719383 0.823132110061124` which is also different from both of these results.

---

Why does this python code not give the same output as the C code? Did I incorrectly implement something?

Code:

```
class RandomGenerators:
  # period parameters
  N = 624
  M = 394
  MATRIX_A = 0x9908b0df    # constant vector a
  UPPER_MASK = 0x80000000  # most significant w-r bits
  LOWER_MASK = 0x7fffffff  # least significant r bits

  def __init__(self):
    self.mt = [None]
    self.mti = self.N + 1

  '''
  initialize by an array with array-length
  init_key is the array for initializing keys
  key_length is its length
  slight change for C++, 2004/2/26
  '''
  def init_by_array(self, init_key, key_length):
    #int i, j, k;
    self.init_genrand(19650218)
    i,j = 1,0
    k = self.N if self.N > key_length else key_length
    #k = (self.N > key_length ? self.N : key_length)
    #for (; k; k--) {
    while k > 0:
      self.mt[i] = (self.mt[i] ^ ((self.mt[i-1] ^ (self.mt[i-1] >> 30)) * 1664525)) + init_key[j] + j # non linear 
      self.mt[i] &= 0xffffffff # for WORDSIZE > 32 machines 
      i+=1
      j+=1
      if i >= self.N:
        self.mt[0] = self.mt[self.N-1]
        i = 1
      if j >= key_length:
        j = 0
      k-=1

    k = self.N-1
    #for (k=N-1; k; k--) {
    while k > 0:
      self.mt[i] = (self.mt[i] ^ ((self.mt[i-1] ^ (self.mt[i-1] >> 30)) * 1566083941)) - i # non linear 
      self.mt[i] &= 0xffffffff # for WORDSIZE > 32 machines 
      i += 1
      if i >= self.N:
        self.mt[0] = self.mt[self.N-1]
        i=1
      k-=1

    self.mt[0] = 0x80000000 # MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array

  # initializes mt[N] with a seed
  def init_genrand(self,s):
    self.mt[0] = s & 0xffffffff
    self.mti = 1
    while self.mti < self.N:
      self.mt.append(1812433253 * (self.mt[self.mti-1] ^ (self.mt[self.mti - 1] >> 30)) + self.mti)
      self.mt[self.mti] &= 0xffffffff
      self.mti += 1

  # generates a random number on [0,0xffffffff]-interval
  def genrand_int32(self):
    y = 0
    mag01=[0x0, self.MATRIX_A]
    if self.mti >= self.N: # generate N words at one time
      kk = 0
      if self.mti == self.N + 1: # if init_genrand() has not been called,
        self.init_genrand(5489) # a default initial seed is used

      while kk < self.N - self.M:
        y = (self.mt[kk] & self.UPPER_MASK) | (self.mt[kk+1] & self.LOWER_MASK)
        self.mt[kk] = self.mt[kk+self.M] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1]
        kk += 1

      while kk < self.N - 1:
        y = (self.mt[kk] & self.UPPER_MASK) | (self.mt[kk+1] & self.LOWER_MASK)
        self.mt[kk] = self.mt[kk+(self.M-self.N)] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1]
        kk += 1

      y = (self.mt[self.N-1] & self.UPPER_MASK) | (self.mt[0] & self.LOWER_MASK)
      self.mt[self.N-1] = self.mt[self.M-1] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1]

      self.mti = 0

    y = self.mt[self.mti]
    self.mti += 1

    # Tempering 
    y ^= (y >> 11)
    y ^= (y << 7) & 0x9d2c5680
    y ^= (y << 15) & 0xefc60000
    y ^= (y >> 18)

    return y

  # generates a random number on [0,0x7fffffff]-interval 
  def genrand_int31(self):
    #return (long)(genrand_int32() >> 1)
    return (self.genrand_int32() >> 1)

  # generates a random number on [0,1]-real-interval 
  def genrand_real1(self):
    return self.genrand_int32() * (1.0 / 4294967295.0)
    # divided by 2^32-1 

  # generates a random number on [0,1)-real-interval 
  def genrand_real2(self):
    return self.genrand_int32() * (1.0 / 4294967296.0)
    # divided by 2^32 

  # generates a random number on (0,1)-real-interval 
  def genrand_real3(self):
    return ((self.genrand_int32()) + 0.5) * (1.0 / 4294967296.0)
    # divided by 2^32 

  # generates a random number on [0,1) with 53-bit resolution
  def genrand_res53(self):
    a, b = self.genrand_int32()>>5, self.genrand_int32()>>6 
    return(a * 67108864.0 + b) * (1.0 / 9007199254740992.0)

r = RandomGenerators()
init = [0x123, 0x234, 0x345, 0x456]
length = 4
r.init_by_array(init, length)
for i in range(10):
  print('mt: '+str(r.genrand_int32()))
```

**--EDIT--**

`mt[]` values are not getting initialized correctly. The first few values in C after calling `init_by_array` are:

```
-2147483648
1827812183
1371430253
-735590895
```

In python the first few are:

```
2147483648
1827812183
1371430253
3559376401
```

So it seems the issue is with positive/negative hexadecimals. I modified the `init_by_array` [here](https://repl.it/Gh3G/2) the code below but I'm guessing `genrand_int32` has similar issues (I've tried adding similar code at the end and throughout without fixing the problem):

```
for i,num in enumerate(self.mt):
  if num>=2147483648: # (2**32)/2
    self.mt[i]-=4294967296 # 2**32
```

Comment: I had no idea what a mersenne twister was.  I looked it up in Wikipedia.  They have a python implementation there.  You may want to compare the two; it may help you.

Comment: One possibility is that `mag01` is declared `static` in the original C source, but is just a local variable in your translation, so it's not persistent.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein here is that implementation with two of the seeds C uses and again unique output https://repl.it/GivD

Comment: Any updates? By following the Wikipedia article, the 1st state variable should be 0 (and the next should be 1) if the seed 0 is used, however, seeding from 0 and passing version=1 don't make the 1st state variable 0 using python's random. Do you know why? If the initializer cannot be reproduced (even in the simplest, uint32 case), then reproduceing the random sequence won't be successful either. Try it out: online-python.com/Pxp4KycsCj